# React Firebase get document with UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to React and am trying to connect my frontend to a firebase database, where my user information is stored. I am pulling the user information by creating a query to match up the uid given passed in as a prop to a field in the user document. I was getting the information from the database, but when I refreshed the page, I received the error

> " TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null "

I added a check if the user existed through the auth. However, now my code does not pull from the database because auth.currentUser does not exist. My code is below.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useParams} from 'react'
import { doc, setDoc , collection, getDocs, addDoc, updateDoc, query, where, QuerySnapshot} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import {db} from "../firebaseConfig.js"
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ProfilePage(props) {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("Jonah Park");
    const [major, setMajor] = useState("Computer Science");
    const [bio, setBio] = useState("I am a third-year CS student that loves to play volleyball and run in my free time!");
    const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);
    const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState();

    const shadowStyle = {
        boxShadow: "0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
    }

    const userCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");
    // console.log(props.user.uid);

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const auth = getAuth();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(auth.currentUser){
            const getUsers = async () => {
                let list = [];
                try{
                    const q = query(userCollectionRef, where("uid", "==", props.user.uid));
                    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        list.push(doc.data());
                    });
                    setUserData(list);
                    console.log("worked");
                }
                catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
            getUsers();
        }
        else{
            console.log("didnt");
        }
        console.log(userData);
        // setUsername(userData[0].username);
        // setName(userData[0].name);
        // setMajor(userData[0].major);
        // setBio(userData[0].bio);
    }, [auth.currentUser?.uid]);
```

Comment: Do you realize all of this code is executing client side?

Answer (score 1):

On the first render your effect runs, but does nothing because there is no user yet. Then later, when the user changes, there's nothing to notify your component that it should render again. Since it doesn't rerender, the effect can not rerun.

The fix is to use `onAuthStateChanged` to be notified when the user changes. When it does you can set state, causing the component to rerender. Assuming you're using version 9 of firebase, that looks like this:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
// ...
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
    getAuth(),
    (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    }
  )
  return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

By setting state the component will rerender, which will run your other useEffect and you can put `user` in the dependency array to control it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      // ...
    }
    getUsers();
  }
  // ...
}, [user]);
```